# Gremlin Cluster/Connection not failing with wrong credentials

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Code Requirements:

- User hits the service by the url pattern of /database//collection//entities
- Java attempts to connect to that specific Database & Collection via Gremlin.  If connection fails then return the error to the User
- If connection was successful, Java then runs a pre-built query and returns the results to the User.

Issue I am facing: using the tutorial located at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-java-getting-started/blob/master/src/GetStarted/Program.java, I am building a Cluster followed by a Client Object using the correct credentials; in that when all the configurations are correct it works without any issues.  However if I change any parameter, DATABASE_ID, COLLECTION_ID, or PASSWORD the code will continue past the building of the Cluster and past the cluster running connect() until it attempts to run "client.submit(query)" where it will return a NullPointerException.

**Question**: is there a method built into the Cluster or the Client Object which returns if it has successfully authenticated.

CODE CONSOLE:

```
DATABSE_ID:PURPOSELY_WRONG_DB
COLLECTION_ID:PURPOSELY_WRONG_COLLECTION
PASSWORD:PURPOSELY_WRONG_PASSWORD_TO_TEST_IF_CONNECTION_THROWS_ERROR
QUERY:g.V().count()
START QUERYING GREMLIN SERVER
AT THIS POINT I HAVE PASSED CLIENT.CONNECT()
ABOUT TO SUBMIT THE QUERY.....
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:239)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:195)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Gremlin Server protocol uses [SASL-based authentication](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/dev/provider/#_authentication), and the auth handshake begins when the first request is sent.

Basic handshake sequence as follows:

1. Server receives a request on a new connection.
2. Server sends authentication challenge.
3. Client sends authentication response with credentials.
4. Server checks the credentials and either responds with the results of the original request OR returns invalid creds response.

However, the null pointer exception is not expected.

Can you provide:

- The version of gremlin-java client you are using?
- A sample that repros the issue.
- if it's possible, the response message that GremlinResponseHandler is attempting to read?

See also the Gremlin request/response reference [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/dev/io/#_requestmessage).